# Trouble calling a method in Javafx controller

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, javafx-8

I'm working on a JavaFX application that allows me to insert a new user into mysql database from a sign up form. I already prepared the add user method but how do I call it in the controller?  This is my method:

```
    @Override
    public void adduser(User usr){
        String req="INSERT INTO `fos_user` (`id`, `username`, `username_canonical`, `email`, `email_canonical`, `enabled`, `password`, `roles`, `nom`) "
                + "VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";
         try {
            Statement stm = con.createStatement();
            stm.executeUpdate(req);
            System.out.println("ajout ok");
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
        } 
    }
```

Comment: http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Database-SQL-JDBC/InsertRecordsUsingPreparedStatement.htm

Comment: @DarshanMehta  I've already prepared the connexion to the database in another class. I just need to call the adduser() in the controller.

Comment: It's not about getting the connecton, it's about using `preparedstatement`.

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking. Just call the method: `someObject.adduser(user)` where `someObject` is the object where this method is defined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using PreparedStatement the wrong way.

You don't set the values to your query, so in place of each `?` you have to set a value for example the first `?` mean that you should to set the id, the second username, ... and so on.

```
@Override
public void adduser(User usr){
     String req="INSERT INTO `fos_user` (`id`, `username`, `username_canonical`, `email`, `email_canonical`, `enabled`, `password`, `roles`, `nom`) "
                + "VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";

     try {
        PreparedStatement stm = connection.prepareStatement(req);

        stm.setInt(1, user.getId());
        stm.setString(2, user.getUsername());
        stm.setString(3, user.getUsername_canonical());
        ...

        stm.executeUpdate();//execute your statement
        System.out.println("ajout ok");
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
    }
```

---

**Note**

For the good practice the id should be **auto increment**, so in insertion you don't need to insert it, make this in head.